# Caffe Segmentation Net - softmax_loss_layer ERROR

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, image-segmentation, deconvolution

I am trying to implement a segmentation net for images using caffe. For each image having dimension `3x256x256`, I have a `256x256` ground truth images.
when I launch a train I got this error:

> ```
> I1019 08:50:55.831014  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer data
> I1019 08:50:55.831068  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer data
> I1019 08:50:55.831099  5847 net.cpp:368] data -> data
> I1019 08:50:55.831149  5847 net.cpp:368] data -> label
> I1019 08:50:55.831178  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up data
> I1019 08:50:55.831207  5847 dense_image_data_layer.cpp:41] Opening file /home/ubuntu/full_conv_net/train.txt
> I1019 08:50:55.844880  5847 dense_image_data_layer.cpp:51] Shuffling data
> I1019 08:50:55.847098  5847 dense_image_data_layer.cpp:56] A total of 15000 examples.
> I1019 08:50:55.856138  5847 dense_image_data_layer.cpp:109] output data size: 1,3,256,256
> I1019 08:50:55.856648  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 3 256 256 (196608)
> I1019 08:50:55.856678  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 1 256 256 (65536)
> I1019 08:50:55.856696  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer label_data_1_split
> I1019 08:50:55.856739  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer label_data_1_split
> I1019 08:50:55.856768  5847 net.cpp:410] label_data_1_split <- label
> I1019 08:50:55.856792  5847 net.cpp:368] label_data_1_split -> label_data_1_split_0
> I1019 08:50:55.856828  5847 net.cpp:368] label_data_1_split -> label_data_1_split_1
> I1019 08:50:55.856843  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up label_data_1_split
> I1019 08:50:55.856863  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 1 256 256 (65536)
> I1019 08:50:55.856884  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 1 256 256 (65536)
> I1019 08:50:55.856896  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv1_1
> I1019 08:50:55.856921  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv1_1
> I1019 08:50:55.856940  5847 net.cpp:410] conv1_1 <- data
> I1019 08:50:55.856956  5847 net.cpp:368] conv1_1 -> conv1_1
> I1019 08:50:55.856976  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv1_1
> I1019 08:50:55.857264  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 64 256 256 (4194304)
> I1019 08:50:55.857321  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv1_1_bn
> I1019 08:50:55.857347  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv1_1_bn
> I1019 08:50:55.857367  5847 net.cpp:410] conv1_1_bn <- conv1_1
> I1019 08:50:55.857383  5847 net.cpp:357] conv1_1_bn -> conv1_1 (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:55.857398  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv1_1_bn
> I1019 08:50:55.857949  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 64 256 256 (4194304)
> I1019 08:50:55.857978  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu1_1
> I1019 08:50:55.857997  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu1_1
> I1019 08:50:55.858011  5847 net.cpp:410] relu1_1 <- conv1_1
> I1019 08:50:55.858023  5847 net.cpp:357] relu1_1 -> conv1_1 (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:55.858043  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu1_1
> I1019 08:50:55.858063  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 64 256 256 (4194304)
> I1019 08:50:55.858077  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv1_2
> I1019 08:50:55.858094  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv1_2
> I1019 08:50:55.858113  5847 net.cpp:410] conv1_2 <- conv1_1
> I1019 08:50:55.858132  5847 net.cpp:368] conv1_2 -> conv1_2
> I1019 08:50:55.858155  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv1_2
> I1019 08:50:55.859597  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 64 256 256 (4194304)
> I1019 08:50:55.859625  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv1_2_bn
> I1019 08:50:55.859642  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv1_2_bn
> I1019 08:50:55.859653  5847 net.cpp:410] conv1_2_bn <- conv1_2
> I1019 08:50:55.859670  5847 net.cpp:357] conv1_2_bn -> conv1_2 (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:55.859691  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv1_2_bn
> I1019 08:50:55.861166  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 64 256 256 (4194304)
> I1019 08:50:55.861192  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu1_2
> I1019 08:50:55.861207  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu1_2
> I1019 08:50:55.861217  5847 net.cpp:410] relu1_2 <- conv1_2
> I1019 08:50:55.861240  5847 net.cpp:357] relu1_2 -> conv1_2 (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:55.861261  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu1_2
> I1019 08:50:55.861274  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 64 256 256 (4194304)
> I1019 08:50:55.861285  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer pool1
> I1019 08:50:55.861300  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer pool1
> I1019 08:50:55.861318  5847 net.cpp:410] pool1 <- conv1_2
> I1019 08:50:55.861335  5847 net.cpp:368] pool1 -> pool1
> I1019 08:50:55.861351  5847 net.cpp:368] pool1 -> pool1_mask
> I1019 08:50:55.861371  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up pool1
> I1019 08:50:55.861418  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 64 128 128 (1048576)
> I1019 08:50:55.861438  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 64 128 128 (1048576)
> I1019 08:50:55.861449  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv2_1
> I1019 08:50:55.861465  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv2_1
> I1019 08:50:55.861476  5847 net.cpp:410] conv2_1 <- pool1
> I1019 08:50:55.861495  5847 net.cpp:368] conv2_1 -> conv2_1
> I1019 08:50:55.861517  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv2_1
> I1019 08:50:55.863991  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 128 128 128 (2097152)
> I1019 08:50:55.864022  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv2_1_bn
> I1019 08:50:55.864038  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv2_1_bn
> I1019 08:50:55.864049  5847 net.cpp:410] conv2_1_bn <- conv2_1
> I1019 08:50:55.864068  5847 net.cpp:357] conv2_1_bn -> conv2_1 (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:55.864099  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv2_1_bn
> I1019 08:50:55.864298  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 128 128 128 (2097152)
> I1019 08:50:55.864323  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu2_1
> I1019 08:50:55.864341  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu2_1
> I1019 08:50:55.864351  5847 net.cpp:410] relu2_1 <- conv2_1
> I1019 08:50:55.864365  5847 net.cpp:357] relu2_1 -> conv2_1 (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:55.864378  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu2_1
> I1019 08:50:55.864392  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 128 128 128 (2097152)
> I1019 08:50:55.864401  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv2_2
> I1019 08:50:55.864418  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv2_2
> I1019 08:50:55.864437  5847 net.cpp:410] conv2_2 <- conv2_1
> I1019 08:50:55.864451  5847 net.cpp:368] conv2_2 -> conv2_2
> I1019 08:50:55.864466  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv2_2
> I1019 08:50:55.869410  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 128 128 128 (2097152)
> I1019 08:50:55.869451  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv2_2_bn
> I1019 08:50:55.869469  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv2_2_bn
> I1019 08:50:55.869482  5847 net.cpp:410] conv2_2_bn <- conv2_2
> I1019 08:50:55.869494  5847 net.cpp:357] conv2_2_bn -> conv2_2 (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:55.869508  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv2_2_bn
> I1019 08:50:55.869607  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 128 128 128 (2097152)
> I1019 08:50:55.869632  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu2_2
> I1019 08:50:55.869645  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu2_2
> I1019 08:50:55.869655  5847 net.cpp:410] relu2_2 <- conv2_2
> I1019 08:50:55.869669  5847 net.cpp:357] relu2_2 -> conv2_2 (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:55.869681  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu2_2
> I1019 08:50:55.869695  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 128 128 128 (2097152)
> I1019 08:50:55.869722  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer pool2
> I1019 08:50:55.869740  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer pool2
> I1019 08:50:55.869762  5847 net.cpp:410] pool2 <- conv2_2
> I1019 08:50:55.869776  5847 net.cpp:368] pool2 -> pool2
> I1019 08:50:55.869791  5847 net.cpp:368] pool2 -> pool2_mask
> I1019 08:50:55.869818  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up pool2
> I1019 08:50:55.869838  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 128 64 64 (524288)
> I1019 08:50:55.869849  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 128 64 64 (524288)
> I1019 08:50:55.869859  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv3_1
> I1019 08:50:55.869879  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv3_1
> I1019 08:50:55.869900  5847 net.cpp:410] conv3_1 <- pool2
> I1019 08:50:55.869917  5847 net.cpp:368] conv3_1 -> conv3_1
> I1019 08:50:55.869937  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv3_1
> I1019 08:50:55.879293  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 256 64 64 (1048576)
> I1019 08:50:55.879324  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv3_1_bn
> I1019 08:50:55.879345  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv3_1_bn
> I1019 08:50:55.879370  5847 net.cpp:410] conv3_1_bn <- conv3_1
> I1019 08:50:55.879385  5847 net.cpp:357] conv3_1_bn -> conv3_1 (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:55.879410  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv3_1_bn
> I1019 08:50:55.879452  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 256 64 64 (1048576)
> I1019 08:50:55.879473  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu3_1
> I1019 08:50:55.879487  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu3_1
> I1019 08:50:55.879508  5847 net.cpp:410] relu3_1 <- conv3_1
> I1019 08:50:55.879523  5847 net.cpp:357] relu3_1 -> conv3_1 (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:55.879545  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu3_1
> I1019 08:50:55.879559  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 256 64 64 (1048576)
> I1019 08:50:55.879580  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv3_2
> I1019 08:50:55.879595  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv3_2
> I1019 08:50:55.879611  5847 net.cpp:410] conv3_2 <- conv3_1
> I1019 08:50:55.879645  5847 net.cpp:368] conv3_2 -> conv3_2
> I1019 08:50:55.879667  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv3_2
> I1019 08:50:55.898186  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 256 64 64 (1048576)
> I1019 08:50:55.898214  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv3_2_bn
> I1019 08:50:55.898231  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv3_2_bn
> I1019 08:50:55.898252  5847 net.cpp:410] conv3_2_bn <- conv3_2
> I1019 08:50:55.898272  5847 net.cpp:357] conv3_2_bn -> conv3_2 (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:55.898293  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv3_2_bn
> I1019 08:50:55.898339  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 256 64 64 (1048576)
> I1019 08:50:55.898360  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu3_2
> I1019 08:50:55.898375  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu3_2
> I1019 08:50:55.898394  5847 net.cpp:410] relu3_2 <- conv3_2
> I1019 08:50:55.898411  5847 net.cpp:357] relu3_2 -> conv3_2 (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:55.898435  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu3_2
> I1019 08:50:55.898448  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 256 64 64 (1048576)
> I1019 08:50:55.898470  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv3_3
> I1019 08:50:55.898485  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv3_3
> I1019 08:50:55.898501  5847 net.cpp:410] conv3_3 <- conv3_2
> I1019 08:50:55.898520  5847 net.cpp:368] conv3_3 -> conv3_3
> I1019 08:50:55.898541  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv3_3
> I1019 08:50:55.917057  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 256 64 64 (1048576)
> I1019 08:50:55.917083  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv3_3_bn
> I1019 08:50:55.917099  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv3_3_bn
> I1019 08:50:55.917117  5847 net.cpp:410] conv3_3_bn <- conv3_3
> I1019 08:50:55.917135  5847 net.cpp:357] conv3_3_bn -> conv3_3 (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:55.917157  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv3_3_bn
> I1019 08:50:55.917193  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 256 64 64 (1048576)
> I1019 08:50:55.917214  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu3_3
> I1019 08:50:55.917229  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu3_3
> I1019 08:50:55.917248  5847 net.cpp:410] relu3_3 <- conv3_3
> I1019 08:50:55.917265  5847 net.cpp:357] relu3_3 -> conv3_3 (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:55.917285  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu3_3
> I1019 08:50:55.917301  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 256 64 64 (1048576)
> I1019 08:50:55.917323  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer pool3
> I1019 08:50:55.917340  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer pool3
> I1019 08:50:55.917356  5847 net.cpp:410] pool3 <- conv3_3
> I1019 08:50:55.917371  5847 net.cpp:368] pool3 -> pool3
> I1019 08:50:55.917390  5847 net.cpp:368] pool3 -> pool3_mask
> I1019 08:50:55.917405  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up pool3
> I1019 08:50:55.917425  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 256 32 32 (262144)
> I1019 08:50:55.917441  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 256 32 32 (262144)
> I1019 08:50:55.917459  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv4_1
> I1019 08:50:55.917477  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv4_1
> I1019 08:50:55.917493  5847 net.cpp:410] conv4_1 <- pool3
> I1019 08:50:55.917510  5847 net.cpp:368] conv4_1 -> conv4_1
> I1019 08:50:55.917529  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv4_1
> I1019 08:50:55.954141  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 32 32 (524288)
> I1019 08:50:55.954170  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv4_1_bn
> I1019 08:50:55.954190  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv4_1_bn
> I1019 08:50:55.954208  5847 net.cpp:410] conv4_1_bn <- conv4_1
> I1019 08:50:55.954226  5847 net.cpp:357] conv4_1_bn -> conv4_1 (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:55.954251  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv4_1_bn
> I1019 08:50:55.954305  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 32 32 (524288)
> I1019 08:50:55.954330  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu4_1
> I1019 08:50:55.954344  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu4_1
> I1019 08:50:55.954365  5847 net.cpp:410] relu4_1 <- conv4_1
> I1019 08:50:55.954377  5847 net.cpp:357] relu4_1 -> conv4_1 (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:55.954401  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu4_1
> I1019 08:50:55.954416  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 32 32 (524288)
> I1019 08:50:55.954426  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv4_2
> I1019 08:50:55.954449  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv4_2
> I1019 08:50:55.954463  5847 net.cpp:410] conv4_2 <- conv4_1
> I1019 08:50:55.954475  5847 net.cpp:368] conv4_2 -> conv4_2
> I1019 08:50:55.954495  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv4_2
> I1019 08:50:56.026969  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 32 32 (524288)
> I1019 08:50:56.027006  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv4_2_bn
> I1019 08:50:56.027035  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv4_2_bn
> I1019 08:50:56.027046  5847 net.cpp:410] conv4_2_bn <- conv4_2
> I1019 08:50:56.027078  5847 net.cpp:357] conv4_2_bn -> conv4_2 (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:56.027102  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv4_2_bn
> I1019 08:50:56.027133  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 32 32 (524288)
> I1019 08:50:56.027153  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu4_2
> I1019 08:50:56.027168  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu4_2
> I1019 08:50:56.027179  5847 net.cpp:410] relu4_2 <- conv4_2
> I1019 08:50:56.027204  5847 net.cpp:357] relu4_2 -> conv4_2 (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:56.027220  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu4_2
> I1019 08:50:56.027242  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 32 32 (524288)
> I1019 08:50:56.027256  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv4_3
> I1019 08:50:56.027288  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv4_3
> I1019 08:50:56.027307  5847 net.cpp:410] conv4_3 <- conv4_2
> I1019 08:50:56.027320  5847 net.cpp:368] conv4_3 -> conv4_3
> I1019 08:50:56.027341  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv4_3
> I1019 08:50:56.100551  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 32 32 (524288)
> I1019 08:50:56.100585  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv4_3_bn
> I1019 08:50:56.100603  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv4_3_bn
> I1019 08:50:56.100626  5847 net.cpp:410] conv4_3_bn <- conv4_3
> I1019 08:50:56.100639  5847 net.cpp:357] conv4_3_bn -> conv4_3 (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:56.100666  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv4_3_bn
> I1019 08:50:56.100702  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 32 32 (524288)
> I1019 08:50:56.100735  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu4_3
> I1019 08:50:56.100750  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu4_3
> I1019 08:50:56.100766  5847 net.cpp:410] relu4_3 <- conv4_3
> I1019 08:50:56.100787  5847 net.cpp:357] relu4_3 -> conv4_3 (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:56.100801  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu4_3
> I1019 08:50:56.100824  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 32 32 (524288)
> I1019 08:50:56.100836  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer pool4
> I1019 08:50:56.100862  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer pool4
> I1019 08:50:56.100872  5847 net.cpp:410] pool4 <- conv4_3
> I1019 08:50:56.100888  5847 net.cpp:368] pool4 -> pool4
> I1019 08:50:56.100911  5847 net.cpp:368] pool4 -> pool4_mask
> I1019 08:50:56.100926  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up pool4
> I1019 08:50:56.100949  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 16 16 (131072)
> I1019 08:50:56.100960  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 16 16 (131072)
> I1019 08:50:56.100977  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv5_1
> I1019 08:50:56.100993  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv5_1
> I1019 08:50:56.101009  5847 net.cpp:410] conv5_1 <- pool4
> I1019 08:50:56.101022  5847 net.cpp:368] conv5_1 -> conv5_1
> I1019 08:50:56.101043  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv5_1
> I1019 08:50:56.173538  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 16 16 (131072)
> I1019 08:50:56.173573  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv5_1_bn
> I1019 08:50:56.173593  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv5_1_bn
> I1019 08:50:56.173619  5847 net.cpp:410] conv5_1_bn <- conv5_1
> I1019 08:50:56.173632  5847 net.cpp:357] conv5_1_bn -> conv5_1 (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:56.173660  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv5_1_bn
> I1019 08:50:56.173699  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 16 16 (131072)
> I1019 08:50:56.173724  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu5_1
> I1019 08:50:56.173750  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu5_1
> I1019 08:50:56.173773  5847 net.cpp:410] relu5_1 <- conv5_1
> I1019 08:50:56.173785  5847 net.cpp:357] relu5_1 -> conv5_1 (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:56.173806  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu5_1
> I1019 08:50:56.173820  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 16 16 (131072)
> I1019 08:50:56.173835  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv5_2
> I1019 08:50:56.173851  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv5_2
> I1019 08:50:56.173868  5847 net.cpp:410] conv5_2 <- conv5_1
> I1019 08:50:56.173887  5847 net.cpp:368] conv5_2 -> conv5_2
> I1019 08:50:56.173907  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv5_2
> I1019 08:50:56.247103  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 16 16 (131072)
> I1019 08:50:56.247139  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv5_2_bn
> I1019 08:50:56.247158  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv5_2_bn
> I1019 08:50:56.247177  5847 net.cpp:410] conv5_2_bn <- conv5_2
> I1019 08:50:56.247192  5847 net.cpp:357] conv5_2_bn -> conv5_2 (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:56.247215  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv5_2_bn
> I1019 08:50:56.247246  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 16 16 (131072)
> I1019 08:50:56.247267  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu5_2
> I1019 08:50:56.247282  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu5_2
> I1019 08:50:56.247301  5847 net.cpp:410] relu5_2 <- conv5_2
> I1019 08:50:56.247318  5847 net.cpp:357] relu5_2 -> conv5_2 (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:56.247341  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu5_2
> I1019 08:50:56.247365  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 16 16 (131072)
> I1019 08:50:56.247376  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv5_3
> I1019 08:50:56.247402  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv5_3
> I1019 08:50:56.247419  5847 net.cpp:410] conv5_3 <- conv5_2
> I1019 08:50:56.247434  5847 net.cpp:368] conv5_3 -> conv5_3
> I1019 08:50:56.247503  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv5_3
> I1019 08:50:56.320230  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 16 16 (131072)
> I1019 08:50:56.320261  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv5_3_bn
> I1019 08:50:56.320279  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv5_3_bn
> I1019 08:50:56.320297  5847 net.cpp:410] conv5_3_bn <- conv5_3
> I1019 08:50:56.320317  5847 net.cpp:357] conv5_3_bn -> conv5_3 (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:56.320339  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv5_3_bn
> I1019 08:50:56.320369  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 16 16 (131072)
> I1019 08:50:56.320389  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu5_3
> I1019 08:50:56.320405  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu5_3
> I1019 08:50:56.320426  5847 net.cpp:410] relu5_3 <- conv5_3
> I1019 08:50:56.320441  5847 net.cpp:357] relu5_3 -> conv5_3 (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:56.320461  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu5_3
> I1019 08:50:56.320473  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 16 16 (131072)
> I1019 08:50:56.320493  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer pool5
> I1019 08:50:56.320508  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer pool5
> I1019 08:50:56.320529  5847 net.cpp:410] pool5 <- conv5_3
> I1019 08:50:56.320546  5847 net.cpp:368] pool5 -> pool5
> I1019 08:50:56.320569  5847 net.cpp:368] pool5 -> pool5_mask
> I1019 08:50:56.320585  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up pool5
> I1019 08:50:56.320605  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 8 8 (32768)
> I1019 08:50:56.320617  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 8 8 (32768)
> I1019 08:50:56.320634  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer upsample5
> I1019 08:50:56.320659  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer upsample5
> I1019 08:50:56.320677  5847 net.cpp:410] upsample5 <- pool5
> I1019 08:50:56.320690  5847 net.cpp:410] upsample5 <- pool5_mask
> I1019 08:50:56.320710  5847 net.cpp:368] upsample5 -> pool5_D
> I1019 08:50:56.320731  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up upsample5
> I1019 08:50:56.320755  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 16 16 (131072)
> I1019 08:50:56.320771  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv5_3_D
> I1019 08:50:56.320791  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv5_3_D
> I1019 08:50:56.320806  5847 net.cpp:410] conv5_3_D <- pool5_D
> I1019 08:50:56.320821  5847 net.cpp:368] conv5_3_D -> conv5_3_D
> I1019 08:50:56.320842  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv5_3_D
> I1019 08:50:56.393477  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 16 16 (131072)
> I1019 08:50:56.393512  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv5_3_D_bn
> I1019 08:50:56.393533  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv5_3_D_bn
> I1019 08:50:56.393554  5847 net.cpp:410] conv5_3_D_bn <- conv5_3_D
> I1019 08:50:56.393569  5847 net.cpp:357] conv5_3_D_bn -> conv5_3_D (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:56.393584  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv5_3_D_bn
> I1019 08:50:56.393625  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 16 16 (131072)
> I1019 08:50:56.393646  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu5_3_D
> I1019 08:50:56.393661  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu5_3_D
> I1019 08:50:56.393681  5847 net.cpp:410] relu5_3_D <- conv5_3_D
> I1019 08:50:56.393697  5847 net.cpp:357] relu5_3_D -> conv5_3_D (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:56.393721  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu5_3_D
> I1019 08:50:56.393735  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 16 16 (131072)
> I1019 08:50:56.393754  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv5_2_D
> I1019 08:50:56.393776  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv5_2_D
> I1019 08:50:56.393795  5847 net.cpp:410] conv5_2_D <- conv5_3_D
> I1019 08:50:56.393811  5847 net.cpp:368] conv5_2_D -> conv5_2_D
> I1019 08:50:56.393832  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv5_2_D
> I1019 08:50:56.467021  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 16 16 (131072)
> I1019 08:50:56.467056  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv5_2_D_bn
> I1019 08:50:56.467075  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv5_2_D_bn
> I1019 08:50:56.467093  5847 net.cpp:410] conv5_2_D_bn <- conv5_2_D
> I1019 08:50:56.467109  5847 net.cpp:357] conv5_2_D_bn -> conv5_2_D (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:56.467124  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv5_2_D_bn
> I1019 08:50:56.467166  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 16 16 (131072)
> I1019 08:50:56.467188  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu5_2_D
> I1019 08:50:56.467206  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu5_2_D
> I1019 08:50:56.467269  5847 net.cpp:410] relu5_2_D <- conv5_2_D
> I1019 08:50:56.467284  5847 net.cpp:357] relu5_2_D -> conv5_2_D (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:56.467298  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu5_2_D
> I1019 08:50:56.467319  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 16 16 (131072)
> I1019 08:50:56.467330  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv5_1_D
> I1019 08:50:56.467357  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv5_1_D
> I1019 08:50:56.467380  5847 net.cpp:410] conv5_1_D <- conv5_2_D
> I1019 08:50:56.467397  5847 net.cpp:368] conv5_1_D -> conv5_1_D
> I1019 08:50:56.467418  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv5_1_D
> I1019 08:50:56.540335  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 16 16 (131072)
> I1019 08:50:56.540366  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv5_1_D_bn
> I1019 08:50:56.540387  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv5_1_D_bn
> I1019 08:50:56.540405  5847 net.cpp:410] conv5_1_D_bn <- conv5_1_D
> I1019 08:50:56.540418  5847 net.cpp:357] conv5_1_D_bn -> conv5_1_D (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:56.540434  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv5_1_D_bn
> I1019 08:50:56.540469  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 16 16 (131072)
> I1019 08:50:56.540491  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu5_1_D
> I1019 08:50:56.540506  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu5_1_D
> I1019 08:50:56.540524  5847 net.cpp:410] relu5_1_D <- conv5_1_D
> I1019 08:50:56.540541  5847 net.cpp:357] relu5_1_D -> conv5_1_D (in-place)
> I1019 08:50:56.540566  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu5_1_D
> I1019 08:50:56.540580  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 512 16 16 (131072)
> I1019 08:50:56.540598  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer deconv_1
> I1019 08:50:56.540619  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer deconv_1
> I1019 08:50:56.540637  5847 net.cpp:410] deconv_1 <- conv5_1_D
> I1019 08:50:56.540654  5847 net.cpp:368] deconv_1 -> deconv_1
> I1019 08:50:56.540674  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up deconv_1
> I1019 08:50:56.542743  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 2 47 47 (4418)
> I1019 08:50:56.542790  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer deconv_1_deconv_1_0_split
> I1019 08:50:56.542821  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer deconv_1_deconv_1_0_split
> I1019 08:50:56.542842  5847 net.cpp:410] deconv_1_deconv_1_0_split <- deconv_1
> I1019 08:50:56.542860  5847 net.cpp:368] deconv_1_deconv_1_0_split -> deconv_1_deconv_1_0_split_0
> I1019 08:50:56.542886  5847 net.cpp:368] deconv_1_deconv_1_0_split -> deconv_1_deconv_1_0_split_1
> I1019 08:50:56.542907  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up deconv_1_deconv_1_0_split
> I1019 08:50:56.542924  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 2 47 47 (4418)
> I1019 08:50:56.542943  5847 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 1 2 47 47 (4418)
> I1019 08:50:56.542953  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer loss
> I1019 08:50:56.542980  5847 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer loss
> I1019 08:50:56.543006  5847 net.cpp:410] loss <- deconv_1_deconv_1_0_split_0
> I1019 08:50:56.543018  5847 net.cpp:410] loss <- label_data_1_split_0
> I1019 08:50:56.543031  5847 net.cpp:368] loss -> loss
> I1019 08:50:56.543071  5847 net.cpp:120] Setting up loss
> I1019 08:50:56.543094  5847 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer loss
> F1019 08:50:56.543150  5847 softmax_loss_layer.cpp:56] Check failed: outer_num_ * inner_num_ == bottom[1]->count() (2209 vs. 65536) Number of labels must match number of predictions; e.g., if softmax axis == 1 and prediction shape is (N, C, H, W), label count (number of labels) must be N*H*W, with integer values in {0, 1, ..., C-1}.
> *** Check failure stack trace: ***
>     @     0x7fa27a2cbdaa  (unknown)
>     @     0x7fa27a2cbce4  (unknown)
>     @     0x7fa27a2cb6e6  (unknown)
>     @     0x7fa27a2ce687  (unknown)
>     @     0x7fa27a6ffb58  caffe::SoftmaxWithLossLayer<>::Reshape()
>     @     0x7fa27a642bf2  caffe::Net<>::Init()
>     @     0x7fa27a644952  caffe::Net<>::Net()
>     @     0x7fa27a62abf0  caffe::Solver<>::InitTrainNet()
>     @     0x7fa27a62bbc3  caffe::Solver<>::Init()
>     @     0x7fa27a62bd96  caffe::Solver<>::Solver()
>     @           0x40c5d0  caffe::GetSolver<>()
>     @           0x406611  train()
>     @           0x404bb1  main
>     @     0x7fa2797ddf45  (unknown)
>     @           0x40515d  (unknown)
>     @              (nil)  (unknown)
> Aborted (core dumped)
> ```

What am I doing wrong? How exactly should I tackle this problem ? Is this a problem with my labeling method ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your prediction `shape` does not match the ground truth `shape`. You predict foreground/background probabilities per pixel at the resolution of `47x47` pixels: top shape of `'deconv_1'` is `1x2x47x47` (batch_size=1, 2 probabilities per pixels, for 47x47 pixels). On the other hand, your ground truth labeling is at the resolution of `256x256`.

You need to either decrease the ground truth resolution, or increase the prediction resolution (or both), such that their spatial dimensions would match.

Comment: thanks! that what I did, and now it works. I changed the kernel_size and the padding.